# Horizontally scrollable FlowRow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to implement a component that will display chips in a very similar way how FlowRow display them but also with horizontal scroll.

Basically whenever chip could be even barely visible on the screen it should be placed there and next one should be moved to the next line.

I've been using `LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid` to achieve this effect but it's not enough as it can happen that some of the chips are not visible on the screen (as they were placed outside of the screen area) and there is no information that user can scroll the content.

```
val rows = kotlin.math.ceil(feedback.size / numberOfItemsInRow).toInt()
LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid(
    modifier = Modifier.height(168.dp),
    rows = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(rows),
    horizontalItemSpacing = Spacing.XS,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
) {
    items(feedback, key = { it.id }) {
        FeedbackOption(feedback = it, onFeedbackClick = onFeedbackClick)
    }
}
```

[image]